# Google maps dark grey

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a dark themed google maps based on the #2d2d2d, but I can't get it to work.

I can only edit the styles with hue and saturation and then I only get colors, or it looks really vague. I also tried the style "color" but then my whole map area got one and the same color.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own custom style using the Google [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com).

Comment: These aren't the droids you're looking for... https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: @JoshH haha thanks, updated